# How to make conditions with IF statement right?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

I have question about my IF statement, it just doesn't work :D
I want to check ID, age and salary, if it's bigger than 0, but my code just ignore that, would like to change 0 to some meanings like - if age <= 0 set age = 21 etc
Will glad to see your answers.
Thank you!

```
class Person
{
    private int _age;
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private int _id;

    public Person(int age, string firstName, string lastName, int id)
    {
        _age = age;
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        _id = id;
    }    
    
    public int GetAge()
    {
        return _age;
    }
    public void SetAge(int age)
    {
        if (_age == 0)
            _age = 21;
        else
            _age = age;
    }
    public int GetId()
    {
        return _id;
    }
    public void SetId(int id)
    {
        if (id > 0)
            _id = id;
        else
            _id = 1;
        
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}\tFirst name: {1}\tLast name: {2}\tID: {3}", this._age, this._firstName, this._lastName, this._id);
    }
}

class TestInheritence
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employe[] employees = new[]
        {
            new Employe(21, "John", "Watson", 0)
        };
        employees[0].Print();
    }  
}
```

Comment: By the way, "Get*" and "Set*" methods are Java syntax. In C# you would use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

Comment: You did it right for id, copy that pattern for age

Comment: @CaiusJard but it doesn't work too :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you don't use the setters which have the if statements, you set the variables directly.
So instead of

```
_age = age;
```

You should use

```
setAge(age);
```

Comment: I should use it here ?  public void SetAge(int age)
    {
        if (_age == 0)
            _age = 21;
        else
            _age = age;
    }

Comment: @DaniilGalitskii no, you should use it in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one error:

```cs
public void SetAge(int age)
{
    if (_age == 0)  //<-- This should be age==0, not _age
        _age = 21;
    else
        _age = age;
}
```

You could benefit from using properties. Or actually use your Set methods as the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: Question body text says <=0 btw

Comment: I've written that jsut now but it doesn't work, maybe ia have one more error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setters you codded when updating the variable, so that it gets to the conditional statements in your code.
also, the if statement for age should be :`if(age <= 0) _age = 21;`

Comment: But with combination with method written by @Kevin and PalleDue